# How to tell jQAssistant to scan .git directory in maven?

Tags: jqassistant

I configured jQAssistant in a Maven project to scan jacoco reports:

```
<scanInclude>
    <path>my-maven-submodule/target/site/jacoco</path>
</scanInclude>
```

This works fine. Then I configured jQA to scan a Git repo:

```
<scanInclude>
    <path>.git</path>
</scanInclude>
```

This does not work because the .git directory is not entered. There is no "Entering .git" log message and the Git Scanner Plugin shows in its debug output that no file from this directory is offered. Why? And how do I configure jQA to scan the .git directory?
The standalone program used e.g. by Gradle works fine, there the Git repo gets imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modified and tried it with the Spring Petclinic sample (http://github.com/buschmais/spring-petclinic) - it's working:

```
        <!-- jQAssistant -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jqassistant.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>scan</goal>
                        <goal>analyze</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnViolations>false</failOnViolations>
                        <!--
                        <groups>
                            <group>default</group>
                        </groups>
                        -->
                        <scanIncludes>
                            <scanInclude>
                                <path>.git</path>
                            </scanInclude>
                        </scanIncludes>
                        <reportProperties>
                            <graphml.report.directory>${project.build.directory}/graphml</graphml.report.directory>
                        </reportProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jqassistant.plugin.jpa2</artifactId>
                    <version>${jqassistant.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jqassistant.plugin.graphml</artifactId>
                    <version>${jqassistant.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>de.kontext-e.jqassistant.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jqassistant.plugin.git</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I've just added the Git scanner officially to the petclinic example, you can clone the repository and try it.

Comment: I just notices that using target 'install' it works, but using target 'jqassistant:scan' it doesn't.

Comment: BUT because it is a multi-module maven project, the Git scanner starts as often as the number of sub-modules. Is there a way to tell the jQA maven plugin to scan some directory only once?

Comment: The scanner is executed per module, currently no way to do it per reactor. Is the repository scanned multiple times? I won't expect that... If yes specify "${project.basedir}/.git" instead of ".git" in the configuration.

Comment: Yes, I found exactly the number of submodules of nodes with the same sha key, it is scanned multiple times. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Yes, that works. Now I have every sha key exactly once.